# Vagrant: Make up two identical machines

Tags: vagrant

We have two folders:

- folder1
- folder2

Inside them we've located two identical `Vagrantfile(s)`.

Once we've `vagrant(ed) up` one vm, we are not able to set the other one up. We are gettin gthis error:

> Machine already provisioned.

So, we are trying to `vagrant up` two vms. Nevertheless `vagrant` deals both as one single machine and we're not able to make up two identical vms...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have identical `.vagrant` folder within folder 1 and 2.
Inside the `.vagrant` folder there is the id of the machine so if you have the same `id` file, the 2 folders will reference and operate the same VM.

You need to remove the `.vagrant` folder from `folder2` and run `vagrant up` again, it will create a new VM from this folder.